# Trying to add items into a ComboBox via MFC

Tags: visual-c++, combobox, mfc

I am trying to add items to a `ComboBox` so the user has a choice of what constant to run a calculation with but I cant seem to add items to a `ComboBox` without an error.

```
CComboBox *m_YM = (CComboBox *)GetDlgItem(IDC_COMBO1);
```

I have tried:

```
m_YM->AddString("Wood");

m_YM->Items->Add("Wood");

m_YM.InsertString(0, "Wood");
```

All throw errors. Compiler tells me that:

> The argument type is incompatible with `LPCTSTR`.

No idea what is the meaning.

Comment: Try to put an `L` before or enclosing inside `_T(...)`. Example: `L"Wood"` or  `_T("Wood")`

Comment: The important thing is the middle `T` of  `LPCTSTR`, which means it will automatically decide if your string is Unicode or plain old ASCII, but the string needs to be input properly, so the need to do what i said in my previous comment.

Comment: @sergiol I deleted my answer, why don't you post yours.

Answer (score 3):

The important thing is the middle `T` of `LPCTSTR`, which means it will automatically decide if your string is Unicode or plain old ASCII, but the string needs to be input properly.

Recommended reading: [What are TCHAR, WCHAR, LPSTR, LPWSTR, LPCTSTR (etc.)?](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/76252/What-are-TCHAR-WCHAR-LPSTR-LPWSTR-LPCTSTR-etc)

Try to put an `L` before or enclosing inside `_T(...)`. Example: `L"Wood"` or `_T("Wood")`